# Boyer-Moore String Matching - Good suffix shift

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, boyer-moore

I understand the bad-symbol table. In the good suffix table, shouldn't the distance be calculated as the distance from rightmost occurrence of the pattern to the end of the pattern text ? In that case, shouldn't the below table have all distances (d2) as 1 (except for the last entry which would be 5), because the same pattern would be available to the immediate left of it?

[image]

On similar terms, never understood the below table as well. Any help?

[image]

Reference:

Question - Page 6, question 7.

---

Answer - Page 11

---

The design and analysis of computer algorithms- Anany Levitin ( https://umutzafer.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/solu7.pdf )

Text - [The design and analysis of computer algorithms- Anany Levitin](http://www.vgloop.com/_files/1394454921-126688.pdf) ( Page 263 )

Comment: Please provide a reference in your question that tells us where you got the quoted text and tables from.

Comment: Edited..please find the reference.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know the answer, but the reference / link may help someone else to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good suffix rule is looking for an instance of the already-matched suffix *where the previous character differs*. For example, in the case of the "good suffix" `00` in your first table, the shift seeks an instance of `00` *not preceded by a `0`*.

Why? Because we know that the `0` preceding the "good suffix" didn't match; otherwise we wouldn't be trying to shift.

In the second table, no such instance can be found. So instead, we look for a plausible prefix of the pattern which matches a suffix of the "good suffix".

Comment: Bang on target. After giving it a lot of thought earlier, finally understood the problem after reading your answer in one go.Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things aren't mentioned as explicitly in books as you would want it to be in this type of algorithms, the thing is, look for an occurrence of the matched part with different preceding char means also the one with no preceding char at all that is the case in pattern 01010 when k=1 here the dist between 0 at index 0 which is not preceded by 1(in fact not by anything) and 0 that is matched and preceded by 1 is 4 hence D2=4.

when k=1 suffix 0 of matched part is found as prefix starting at index 0 and distance between these is 4 so D2=4, when k=3 our matched part is preceded by 1 however we see another 010 starting at index 0 not preceded by anything which counts and the distance between these is 2 so D2=2. lastly when k=4 suffix 010 of matched part is found at index 0 which is at a distance of 2 from our suffix 010 so D2 again is 2.